# How is Python class attribute being set without actually being set?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain what's going on in the following? Why on earth does object `b` have the value of object `a`'s list?

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, A = []):
        self.A = A

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.A)

def mutate_A():
    a = Test()
    a.A.append(1)

    return a

def problem_here():
    a = mutate_A()
    b = Test()

    print b  # why does this print [1] in python 2.7

problem_here()
```

Please let me know if I am being unclear or if more information is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in python, the default arguments are evaluated only once (when the function is defined). Therefore, all instances of the class use the same list `A`

If however, you want each instance to have its own list, then you should do:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.A = []

>>> a = mutate_A()
>>> b = Test()
>>> print b
[]
```

Comment: Should mutable default arguments be avoided for this reason? How would you suggest fixing this problem?

Comment: This isn't quite right. The argument is evaluated when the function is defined, not when the function is called for the first time.

Comment: @gjdanis, You shouls avoid it unless you specifically want that feature. How to fix it? I updated my answer

Comment: @IsmailBadawi, Oops sorry, Thought to English mistranslation. Updated. Thanks

Comment: @sshashank124: Thank you. This is quite astonishing...

Comment: @gjdanis, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Comment: The usual fix if you want an argument with a default value that is mutable, but you want to avoid this oddity, is to use `None` as a sentinel value for the default and then use `self.A = A or []` in the body of `__init__`

Comment: @sshashank124: Yes, in 8 minutes.

Comment: @CarlMeyer, Yes. That is what I have done in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @sshashank124 Actually that isn't quite what you've done in your answer. You removed the argument entirely so it is no longer possible to pass in a value for `A`.

Comment: @CarlMeyer it is better to use something like `self.A = A if A is not None else []`, because there are other falsey things that could be passed in.

Comment: @lvc I think it's good to be aware that my boolean version will convert anything falsy to an empty list; I also think that most of the time in practice that is just fine (presuming the only valid inputs for that argument are lists).